# OAuth2 PHP change expiration time

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I use this library : [Oauth2 PHP](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/)

I can't find the setting to change the expiration time, I tried:

```
new OAuth2\Server($this->_mem, array('use_jwt_access_tokens' => true, 'access_token_lifetime' => 2419200));
```

But the lifetime of the token is always 3600. What's the right setting?

**Edit:** As suggested, I tried to use refresh token

```
new OAuth2\Server($this->_mem, array('use_jwt_access_tokens' => true, 'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true));
```

The client_credential grant type + JWT bearer works but I never get a refresh token (only access token). Even upon token verification, I never get a refresh token.

**Edit:** Since the refresh doesn't work for me, as suggested I tried to set the token expiration time doing

```
new OAuth2\Server($this->_mem, array('use_jwt_access_tokens' => true, 'access_lifetime' => 12000));
```

The response upon client credential still returns a short token

```
{ ["access_token"]=> string(648) "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6ImU0NjE0MzdhMjY2YjFkNWY0OWU5MDY5MjQwODg5NjU0MDI2ZGRmODAiLCJpc3MiOiIiLCJhdWQiOiI4OWM2MjRmNTNiYTVmOTM3NjFmZWFhNmU1MGI1ZDk1NGQ4ZGRjMTIxIiwic3ViIjpudWxsLCJleHAiOjE0MzQ0NjI2NDIsImlhdCI6MTQzNDQ1OTA0MiwidG9rZW5fdHlwZSI6ImJlYXJlciIsInNjb3BlIjoicHVibGljIHJlYWRfbmV3cyJ9.Mk_KyUk_8yPnq9eEjvgVOJXBOkQSifAPbEaUvY4X9WvfmImPnC7PJx_99ODpiJR_gMLhZ3gBl1gQEJ2z6xUZ83dntCYzGWumkVLNpJG8omuVkmZqNnbLYYXl-vzmGOblceeDrKw_lrXc4rb72BeFaMeZWwFV7YMrgA0LOsYyZmAiDblcbHtpPGpUd2EC3y7VxLnyA8u07eY4aswOHwClPlDwHX_HwfMUmDLWkoTcrRf1AvKn-cnj41eL0SU9AJHWab8AOK7lxDsaqnits5pXj--cG9hr8pWOsFPQ2D9qYOsMvbEOi4zDJEdaIp-qvzn6N5Wrm5GxdbU1AqwvM531hQ" ["expires_in"]=> int(3600) ["token_type"]=> string(6) "bearer" ["scope"]=> string(16) "public" }
```

It appears it was a cache issue, the token is now set to the proper expiration length/time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `access_token` lifetime using the `access_lifetime` `OAuth2\Server` config parameter from examining [the code](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php).

The `access_lifetime` config parameter is used in creating the token in [`OAuth2\ResponseType\JwtAccessToken` line 63](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/ResponseType/JwtAccessToken.php):

```
$expires = time() + $this->config['access_lifetime'];
```

This can be set when instantiating the server which takes the following config parameters as listed in [`OAuth2\Server` lines 109 - 126](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Server.php).

```
    // merge all config values.  These get passed to our controller objects
    $this->config = array_merge(array(
        'use_jwt_access_tokens'        => false,
        'store_encrypted_token_string' => true,
        'use_openid_connect'       => false,
        'id_lifetime'              => 3600,
        'access_lifetime'          => 3600,
        'www_realm'                => 'Service',
        'token_param_name'         => 'access_token',
        'token_bearer_header_name' => 'Bearer',
        'enforce_state'            => true,
        'require_exact_redirect_uri' => true,
        'allow_implicit'           => false,
        'allow_credentials_in_request_body' => true,
        'allow_public_clients'     => true,
        'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => false,
        'unset_refresh_token_after_use' => true,
    ), $config);
```

There is also support for refresh tokens according to the code for `Server.php` and `JwtAccessToken.php`.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha: Why do you mention Google? The Question mentions OAuth 2.0 Server PHP, not Google. Anyone can create a OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server following [RFC 6749](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749), including Facebook, LinkedIn, Google, and anyone running the project listed in the OP: OAuth 2.0 Server PHP.

Comment: It worked, it was trapped in the server cache, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

In server.php (where you are passing grant type and client credentials)

```
$config = array(
    'access_lifetime' => 86400
);
$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage, $config);
```

source: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/issues/699